# Excel VBA code stops if value is zero or blank

Tags: vba, excel

The code is running inaccurately, the formula is:

F(cells) = G(cells) - A2 Only if F(cells) > 0

```
Private Sub Button_Click()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Dim cell As range
Call TrimExcessSpaces

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic


End If
End Sub
```

When the code runs and find any "blank" or "0" value in a cell of F, the code stops working although the next F.cell might have a positive value. The point is we need the code to continue working if the next cell has positive value.

A screenshot to better explain
[image: The code stops here]

The correct result should be as below screenshot to consider the code working.
[image: The correct result]

Comment: You use & where I think you mean And. & is string concatenation operator. And is the boolean operator.

Comment: You're also missing and `End If`. You have `If / Else / If / If`. You need `If / Else / End If / If / End If / If / End If` the way you have it now.  Does your code compile correctly or are you perhaps leaving out the final `End If`?

Comment: I'm aware of the concatenation and I used And and & however yet I'm not getting accurate results.

Comment: @BruceWayne this is part of the code and yes it's compiling correctly however not getting accurate results

Comment: Can we see the rest of your code? It looks a little convoluted/overkill to be what seems to be `=IF(AND(F1>0,F1<>""),F1-$A$2,"")`

Answer (score 1):

Actually only one line of code is required when you are trying to populate the column G based on column F values.

In the example code below, you just need to call the sub PopulateColumnG within your main sub routine.

**Main sub routine:**

```
Private Sub Button_Click()

    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Call PopulateColumnG

    'Rest of your code


    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```

**Code required to populate column G:**

```
Sub PopulateColumnG()
    Dim lr As Long
    lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("G1:G" & lr).Formula = "=IF(F1>0,F1-$A$2,"""")"
    Range("G1:G" & lr).Value = Range("G1:G" & lr).Value
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for the answer however I'm not sure this is exactly what I"m looking for if you check the code posted you can see I'm calling multiple subs into this button and requesting to compile certain formula to achieve the results

Comment: If not mistaken, ".ScreenUpdating = True" is a moot set since it kicks in anyway, once code finishes.